# MySQL Where Date (not datetime) as Week of year

Tags: php, mysql, date, symfony, doctrine

I have the following query using Symfony2, I want to convert `i.fechaInicio` which is `date` field `Y-m-d` (2013-08-31) to current week number so I can fetch results from current week...

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$semana = $now->format('W'); // Week Number
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
->createQuery("
        SELECT i
        FROM PgeIncidenciasBundle:Incidencia i
        WHERE i.fechaInicio = :semana // This is wrong because compares
                                      // Y-m-d with W so no results found...
        ")
->setParameters(array(
    'semana' => $semana
))
;
try {
    return $query->getResult();
}
catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: start working on your accept ratio. If your questions are answered accept answer or tell that answers are not ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator :

```
$from = new DateTime;
$from->setIsoDate($from->format('o'), $from->format('W'));
$to = clone $from;
$to->modify('+6 day');

$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("
        SELECT i
        FROM PgeIncidenciasBundle:Incidencia i
        WHERE i.fechaInicio BETWEEN :from AND :to
    ")
    ->setParameters(array(
        'from' => $from->format('Y-m-d'),
        'to' => $to->format('Y-m-d'),
    ));
```

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution using `WHERE IN()` and generating an array of dates for current week.

```
public function findCounter()
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $semana = $now->format('Y-m-d');
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("
                SELECT i
                FROM PgeIncidenciasBundle:Incidencia i
                WHERE i.fechaInicio IN (:semana)
                ")
        ->setParameters(array(
            'semana' => $this->week_from_monday($semana)
        ))
        ;
        try {
            return $query->getResult();
        }
        catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

private function week_from_monday($date) {
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date);
    $wkday = date('l',mktime('0','0','0', $month, $day, $year));
    switch($wkday) {
        case 'Monday': $numDaysToMon = 0; break;
        case 'Tuesday': $numDaysToMon = 1; break;
        case 'Wednesday': $numDaysToMon = 2; break;
        case 'Thursday': $numDaysToMon = 3; break;
        case 'Friday': $numDaysToMon = 4; break;
        case 'Saturday': $numDaysToMon = 5; break;
        case 'Sunday': $numDaysToMon = 6; break;
    }
    $monday = mktime('0','0','0', $month, $day-$numDaysToMon, $year);
    $seconds_in_a_day = 86400;
    for($i=0; $i<7; $i++)
    {
    $dates[$i] = date('Y-m-d',$monday+($seconds_in_a_day*$i));
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you vote negative to my own answer as there were no valid answers to my question, but thank you.

Comment: Because there is valid answer ;) Maybe the downvote was because you are using `WHERE IN()` for date compare operations. This example is only returning 7 dates, but what if you have like 2 year difference when comparing dates in SQL? That would mean that your `WHERE IN (...)` will have 700+ dates in it; which is overkill. Just bad practice IMHO. p.s. There will always be downvoters that don't explain why they downvoted. I have few examples, where people downvoted my answer because I downvoted there with explanation.

Comment: I understand that My answer is not a good practice, but at the time I posted, there weren't any other valid answers (as you can see I marked as correct answer yours) But whatever, thank you for your answer (both of them :))